# Website layout using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sorry for bad english, i'm using google translate!

I have created a site using flexbox - codepen.io/anon/pen/zPwjRp. Applied @media for a width site of less than 700 pixels. It seems all right, but as soon as the width of the window becomes less than 717px the following problem appears:

1. Horizontal scrollbar
2. Right sidebar moves a little beyond the permissible border
3. Block with the main content also goes to the right (it is clear that there is an indent on the left, but there is no indent visible to the right).

Guys & girls, please help!

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Issues 1 and 3 happen because of the left and right margin. 
Add this

```
.content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
```

to your media query, check the full code below:

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  font: 15px Tahoma;
  color: #00C8FF;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  background: #263238;
}

#header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
}


/* Глобальный блок обертка */

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}


/* Все сайдбары фиксированной ширины */

.sidebar {
  width: 202px;
  min-width: 202px;
}


/* У первых сайдбаров убираем отступ */

.sidebar-item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* У остальных делаем отступ друг от друга */

.sidebar-item {
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Верхний и нижний фон сайдбара идентичного цвета и одинаковой высоты */

.sitem-top-bg,
.sitem-bottom-bg {
  height: 84px;
  background: #3e2723;
}


/* Средний фон с выравниванием текста по центру */

.sitem-middle-bg {
  background: #5d4037;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Обертка основного содержимого */

.content-wrapper {
  width: 68%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Выстраиваем в одну линию несколько верхних фонов и поровну делим расстояние между блоками */

.cw-top-bg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Все верхние фоны имеют идентичную высоту */

.cw-top-bg-left,
.cw-top-bg-middle,
.cw-top-bg-right {
  height: 40px;
}


/* Верхний левый и правый блок с минимальной шириной */

.cw-top-bg-left,
.cw-top-bg-right {
  min-width: 134px;
  background: #212121;
}


/* Верхний средний фон */

.cw-top-bg-middle {
  width: 100%;
  background: #424242;
}


/* Выстраиваем все средние и нижние блоки основного содержимого в линию */

.cw-middle-bg,
.cw-bottom-bg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Боковые полосы */

.cw-middle-bg-left,
.cw-middle-bg-right {
  width: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background: #607d8b;
}


/* Средний фон с основным содержимым */

.cw-middle-bg-center {
  color: #137DE6;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(29, 26, 26, 0.64);
}

.cw-bottom-bg-left,
.cw-bottom-bg-right {
  width: 68px;
  min-width: 68px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #382f2f;
}

.cw-bottom-bg-middle {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sidebar {
    align-self: center;
  }
  .content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h3>Шапка с логотипом</h3>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Обертка для сайдбаров !-->
  <div class="sidebar">

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Обертка основного содержимого !-->
  <div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="cw-top-bg">
      <div class="cw-top-bg-left"></div>
      <div class="cw-top-bg-middle"></div>
      <div class="cw-top-bg-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cw-middle-bg">
      <div class="cw-middle-bg-left"></div>
      <div class="cw-middle-bg-center">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at dui mattis, convallis justo nec, auctor augue. Nulla vel lacinia nisi. Duis nec dolor nibh. Pellentesque elementum urna nec viverra venenatis. Aenean commodo pellentesque ante.
          Nullam quis mi egestas, volutpat ipsum sed, hendrerit diam. Fusce ut ligula a magna molestie feugiat sed at quam. Maecenas porta, metus sed sodales molestie, ex lacus porttitor nisl, vel lobortis sem tellus vel risus. Phasellus erat massa, scelerisque
          id augue vel, volutpat lacinia lectus. Etiam efficitur, purus vitae ultricies ultricies, massa est vestibulum nisi, eu tincidunt diam velit id diam. Duis elementum tristique pellentesque. Nunc erat tortor, convallis sed sodales a, luctus quis
          nunc.


      </div>
      <div class="cw-middle-bg-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cw-bottom-bg">
      <div class="cw-bottom-bg-left"></div>
      <div class="cw-bottom-bg-middle"></div>
      <div class="cw-bottom-bg-right"></div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- Обертка для сайдбаров !-->
  <div class="sidebar">

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Обертка для отдельных блоков сайдбаров !-->
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <!-- Верхний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-top-bg"></div>
      <!-- Средний фон сайдбара!-->
      <div class="sitem-middle-bg">
        Какое нибудь содержимое
      </div>
      <!-- Нижний фон сайдбара !-->
      <div class="sitem-bottom-bg"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```